# Outlier detection with elliptic envelope - unexpected error

Tags: scikit-learn, outlier, linear-algebra

I am trying to detect outliers with `sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope` for a single variable, but it throws an unexpected error. Here is an example the reproduces the error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.covariance import EllipticEnvelope

data = [1,2,2,2,2,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value'])

def OutlierDetection(data):
    X = data[['value']]
    detector = EllipticEnvelope(support_fraction=1, contamination=0.1)
    model = detector.fit(X)
    prediction = model.predict(X)
    score = model.decision_function(X)
    return data.assign(score=score, prediction=prediction)

OutlierDetection(df)
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN.
```

I get the same result if the data is constant (e.g. just 2's), which is not surprising to me. I suspect it may have something to do with how the algorithm is implemented, but I don't really know.

I hope someone can help.